# Can quarantine marker be refreshed as an action in Pandemic State of Emergency?

Tags: pandemic-state-of-emergency

Can I upgrade a quarantine marker from its “1”-side to its “2”-side as an action?

The rules only mention placing a fresh marker (on its “2”-side), and that it is not possible to place two markers...

Answer (score 4):

No you can't as the rules specifically state that you place a quarantine market at level 2 as an action. If you where able to upgrade it then it would include that in the rules.

[Rules](https://images-cdn.zmangames.com/us-east-1/filer_public/0d/f7/0df79f91-9331-47d6-8401-9df2ab6063dc/zm7113_pandemic_soe_rules.pdf)

> As an action, a player may impose a quarantine on the city he is in by
>   placing a quarantine marker in that city with its "2" side face up. A player
>   may not put a quarantine marker in a city that already has one.

Answer (score 0):

The rules state:

> As an action, a player may impose a quarantine on the city he is in by
>   placing a quarantine marker in that city with its "2" side face up. A player
>   may not put a quarantine marker in a city that already has one.

The rules explicitly state what allowed actions are. And since flipping quarantine markers is not mentioned, it is not an allowed action.

I believe the expansion does come with blank event cards, so you could create an event that lets you flip a couple quarantine markers back to the "1" side.